# While converting string to date, the first day of a given month is being converted into the last day of the previous month

Tags: javascript, datetime

While converting string to date, **the first day of a given month is being converted into the last day of the previous month**. For instance, here I'm converting the first day of October but getting the last day of September.

```
const fyStr = +this.fiscalYear - 1 + '-10-01';       //fyStr = "2019-10-01"
const startDate = new Date(fyStr);                   //startDate = Mon Sep 30 2019 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
```

I change the date to be the **first day of November**, and now I'm getting the **last day of October**.

```
const fyStr = +this.fiscalYear - 1 + '-11-01';       //fyStr = "2019-11-01"
const startDate = new Date(fyStr);                   //startDate = Mon Oct 31 2019 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Since you're not providing a time in your format, it's subtracting your TZ offset. To avoid, looks like you can do `new Date('11-01-2019')`. `new Date('2019-11-01')` yields `Thu Oct 31 2019 20:00:00 GMT-0400` while `new Date('11-01-2019')` yields `Fri Nov 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400`. If you use the format YYYY-MM-DD as you did, then per documentation, The computed date will be relative to your time zone.

Comment: @Brant I think `new Date('11-01-2019')` would only work in the north America where the date format is month date year. Here in Spain I get an Invalid date error.

Comment: @Richard77 2019-11-01 UTC is 8pm the day before in your time zone. Try `new Date(fyStr).toDateString()` or `new Date(fyStr).toISOString()` PS presumably this happens with any date, not just the 1st of each month?

Comment: @Frazer, I see. It's just how I first noticed the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you gave the date `"2019-10-01"` to new Date(). The function reads it this way `"2019-10-01 00:00:00 GMT"` then it proceeds to converting it to your time zone GMT-4 which is `"2019-09-30 20:00:00 GMT-4"`.

So you have two solutions either you specify the timezone in you input.

Or since the output is in our timezone, you convert it to UTC/GMT:

```js
var dt = new Date('2019-10-01');

console.log(dt.toUTCString());
```